# Can't Access SQLite3 Database With pypyodbc

Tags: python, sqlite, odbc, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I am switching a python program over from my Windows laptop which had Microsoft SQL Studio 18 on it to a raspberry pi so I can keep it running 24/7. On the laptop, it worked just fine using pyodbc to connect to the local Microsoft SQL Server, but on the raspberry pi, it isn't working. I first had to switch out pyodbc for pypyodbc because there was an issue with the pip installation for pyodbc. Then, I had the database copied over as an .sql file and turned it into a .db file with SQLite3. However, the suggested Driver value for SQLite3 in the pypyodbc.connect() function, `Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver` is throwing the error

('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQLite3 ODBC Driver' : file not found")

I have no idea how to solve this. I tried to download Microsoft SQL Server for Linux Debian 9, but it couldn't find the msodbcsql18 library. I tried to install FreeTDS ODBC, but my terminal doesn't recognize the tsql command, for some reason. I have not been able to locate this mythical "odbc.ini", either. I've been pulling my hair out over what should have been the most trivial step in this transition, and I need help. Anything you can tell me about will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why try to connect using odbc at all? Python usually has a sqlite3 library as part of the standard library. You could probably replace your `pypdbc.connect()` call with `sqlite3.connect(/path/to/db/file)`

Comment: The reason is because I only know pyodbc.connect(), but I will try to switch to sqlite3.connect. Will post the results once I make the switch.

Comment: Ahh yeah would love to hear how it goes! One great thing about working with SQL dbs in python is that the client libraries usually follow PEP249, the DBAPI spec, pretty closely. It makes it so that if you know how to use one, you can usaully get the basics of how to use another one.

Comment: sqlite3 was a perfect replacement! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome :) I guess I should repeat this as answer huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a step back and ask if ODBC is the right interface for interacting with Sqlite3 from a raspberry pi. Python should come with a sqlite3 library as part of its standard library, it should be a pretty straightforward replacement.

So rather than having:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect(<args)
```

You'll have

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/file/db')
```

That connection object should work mostly the same as the one you got from pypyodbc, assuming that library follow's the DBAPI standard, which most python SQL libraries do.